# why this small datacollection-config.xml is not valid in opennms?

Tags: opennms

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<datacollection-config rrdRepository="/var/lib/opennms/rrd/snmp/">
  <snmp-collection name="default" snmpStorageFlag="select">
    <rrd step="300">
      <rra>RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:1:2016</rra>
      <rra>RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:12:1488</rra>
      <rra>RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:288:366</rra>
      <rra>RRA:MAX:0.5:288:366</rra>
      <rra>RRA:MIN:0.5:288:366</rra>
    </rrd>

<resourceType name="testResourceType" label="ciscotestgroup" >
  <persistenceSelectorStrategy class="org.opennms.netmgt.collectd.PersistAllSelectorStrategy"/>
  <storageStrategy class="org.opennms.netmgt.dao.support.FrameRelayStorageStrategy"/>
</resourceType>

  <group name="ciscotestgroup" ifType="all">
    <mibObj oid=".1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10"     instance="ifIndex" alias="ifInOctets"      type="counter" />
  </group>

  <systemDef name="cisco-routers-test">
    <sysoidMask>.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.1.</sysoidMask>
    <collect>
      <includeGroup>ciscotestgroup</includeGroup>
    </collect>
  </systemDef>
```

Hello Friends,

I am trying weeks for getting only the required small subset of snmp data from all interfaces in a cisco router.
Verifying with opennms wiki help little. Still Its not restarting with the above datacollection-config.xml file.

If i replace with the one below, opennms is starting and working.
I am suspecting resourceType name and group instace variable.
anybody please tell me what is logically/technically wrong in the above config file.....
(I replaced ifIndex to testResourceType, but still not working)

Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<datacollection-config rrdRepository="/var/lib/opennms/rrd/snmp/">
  <snmp-collection name="default" snmpStorageFlag="select">
    <rrd step="300">
      <rra>RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:1:2016</rra>
      <rra>RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:12:1488</rra>
      <rra>RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:288:366</rra>
      <rra>RRA:MAX:0.5:288:366</rra>
      <rra>RRA:MIN:0.5:288:366</rra>
    </rrd>

<resourceType name="frCircuitIfIndex" label="Frame-Relay Circuit (RFC1315)">
  <persistenceSelectorStrategy class="org.opennms.netmgt.collectd.PersistAllSelectorStrategy"/>
  <storageStrategy class="org.opennms.netmgt.dao.support.FrameRelayStorageStrategy"/>
</resourceType>


<groups>
  <group name="cisco-frame-relay" ifType="all">
    <mibObj oid=".1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.49.1.2.2.1.1" instance="frCircuitIfIndex" alias="frIfName"     type="string" />
    <mibObj oid=".1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.49.1.2.2.1.2" instance="frCircuitIfIndex" alias="frIfType"     type="string" />
    <mibObj oid=".1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.49.1.2.2.1.3" instance="frCircuitIfIndex" alias="frSubifIndex" type="string" />
    <mibObj oid=".1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.49.1.2.1.1.1" instance="frCircuitIfIndex" alias="frDEins"        type="counter" />
    <mibObj oid=".1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.49.1.2.1.1.2" instance="frCircuitIfIndex" alias="frDEouts"       type="counter" />
    <mibObj oid=".1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.49.1.2.1.1.3" instance="frCircuitIfIndex" alias="frDropPktsOuts" type="counter" />
  </group>

  <group name="rfc1315-frame-relay" ifType="all">
    <mibObj oid=".1.3.6.1.2.1.10.32.2.1.1" instance="frCircuitIfIndex" alias="frIfIndex"        type="string" />
    <mibObj oid=".1.3.6.1.2.1.10.32.2.1.2" instance="frCircuitIfIndex" alias="frDlci"           type="string" />
    <mibObj oid=".1.3.6.1.2.1.10.32.2.1.3" instance="frCircuitIfIndex" alias="frState"          type="string" />
    <mibObj oid=".1.3.6.1.2.1.10.32.2.1.4" instance="frCircuitIfIndex" alias="frReceivedFECNs"  type="Counter" />
    <mibObj oid=".1.3.6.1.2.1.10.32.2.1.5" instance="frCircuitIfIndex" alias="frReceivedBECNs"  type="Counter" />
    <mibObj oid=".1.3.6.1.2.1.10.32.2.1.6" instance="frCircuitIfIndex" alias="frSentFrames"     type="Counter" />
    <mibObj oid=".1.3.6.1.2.1.10.32.2.1.7" instance="frCircuitIfIndex" alias="frSentOctets"     type="Counter" />
    <mibObj oid=".1.3.6.1.2.1.10.32.2.1.8" instance="frCircuitIfIndex" alias="frReceivedFrames" type="Counter" />
    <mibObj oid=".1.3.6.1.2.1.10.32.2.1.9" instance="frCircuitIfIndex" alias="frReceivedOctets" type="Counter" />
  </group>

</groups>

<systems>

  <systemDef name="Cisco Routers">
    <sysoidMask>.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.1.</sysoidMask>
    <collect>
      <includeGroup>rfc1315-frame-relay</includeGroup>
      <includeGroup>cisco-frame-relay</includeGroup>
    </collect>
  </systemDef>

</systems>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the enclosing `<systems>` and `<groups>` tags are mandatory but missing in your example.

```
<groups>
  <group name="ciscotestgroup" ifType="all">
    <mibObj oid=".1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10"     instance="ifIndex" alias="ifInOctets"      type="counter" />
  </group>
</groups>

<systems>
  <systemDef name="cisco-routers-test">
    <sysoidMask>.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.1.</sysoidMask>
    <collect>
      <includeGroup>ciscotestgroup</includeGroup>
    </collect>
  </systemDef>
</systems>
```